# Error al realizar una Consulta con con JOIN y COUNT en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subconsultas

Un saludo a todos, tengo un problema al realizar una consulta que básicamente es que necesito saber la cantidad que hay de empleados por ciudad.
El resultado queda asi.

[image]

Me parece que el error es porque en la tabla empleado no hace referencia con la tabla ubicación, pero si con la tabla departamento, por lo que tendría que haber una referencia intermedia entre ubicacion y departamento pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo

Este es el código que intenté

```
SELECT u.ciudad AS 'Ciudad',
COUNT(e.idempleado) AS 'Cantidad de empleados'
FROM RH..ubicacion AS u
left join RH..empleado AS e
    ON u.idubicacion = e.idempleado
GROUP BY u.ciudad;
go
```

adjunto tambien el modelo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Si pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto de los temas de SQL y su lenguaje
también veo que uno esta con valor CHAR y el otro con INT

Comment: Pero es que actualmente estás haciendo `JOIN` entre 2 tablas que no están relacionadas entre sí, por 2 columnas que no tienen nada que ver entre sí: `idempleado` por qué sería igual que `idubicacion`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dices, tienes que unir `empleado` con `departamento` y ésta con `ubicacion` usando los ids que sirven de llaves foráneas y primarias respectivamente. Por ejemplo el id del empleado no sirve de nada aquí para los JOIN, porque esa columna no se relaciona con las otras tablas.

Revisa también el `GROUP BY`, en ciertos contextos puede haber varias ciudades distintas que se llamen igual (por ejemplo si hay posibilidad de diferentes países o regiones), por eso he agrupado también por el id.

Así debería funcionar:

```
SELECT 
    u.ciudad AS 'Ciudad',
    COUNT(e.idempleado) AS 'Cantidad de empleados'
FROM RH..empleado AS e
    LEFT JOIN RH..departamento AS d ON e.idepartamento = d.iddepartamento
    LEFT JOIN RH..ubicacion AS u ON d.idubicacion = u.idubicacion
GROUP BY u.idubicacion, u.ciudad;
```

Si sólo quieres mostrar las ciudades que tengan empleados, cambia los `LETF JOIN`  por `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, justo se me ocurrió hacer algo parecido y me ganaste.

Comment: Como explica el Colega @A. Cedano es la forma correcta por que el left join solo carga una parte del conjunto de datos de AUB y en este caso son AUBUC,